# Запрос с максимальным значением столбца

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть таблица с заказами `waybill_items`, в которой `waybill` - это номер заказа, а `name` - наименование. На один заказ может выйти несколько наименований.

Как можно сделать выборку по последнему заказу (у него, получается, максимальное значение `waybill`) всех наименований?

Если я использую обычную функцию `MAX`, то он выдает только одну строчку из наименования, а у меня их около 20.

```
SELECT MAX(waybill), name FROM waybill_items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в подзапросе вычислить макс. значение `waybill`, после чего использовать его в `WHERE` для выбора строк с таким значением `waybill`:

```
SELECT * FROM waybill_items
WHERE waybill = (SELECT MAX(waybill) FROM waybill_items)
```

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось